# Display MySQL datetime in users timezone

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, timezone

MySQL datetimes created using `now()` are stored as UTC.

Client side timezone is detected using JavaScript and returned as `"Europe/London"`.

What is the best way to select the datetime from MySQL and display the created time in the users local time?

PHP and Node are both used with MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MySQL [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Europe/London')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you logic is made, but I'm using this in PHP:

```
function utc_to_timezone($format, $date, $to_timezone)
{
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($to_timezone));

    return $date->format($format);
}
```

Example:

```
echo utc_to_timezone('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2014-07-04 15:34:23', 'Europe/London');
```